# How to download a file without using <a> element with download attribute or a server?

Tags: javascript, html, file, download, fileapi

According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) the [`download`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#downloading-resources) attribute of [`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) element is supported at [Microsoft Edge build 10547+](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/adownloadattribute), but [not IE or Safari](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Browser_compatibility).

How to download a file object without using `<a>` element with `download` attribute set or a server?

Comment: You can check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524320/download-pdf-file-from-ajax-response/38552959#38552959 It gives exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @Dekel See criteria at OP, `.responseType` was not defined at that point in browser development.

Comment: are you looking for a solution for 2016-browser-compatible or 2017? :)

Comment: @Dekel Will not try to change the context of the original Question after the fact. See [How to create an ArrayBuffer and data URI from Blob and File objects without FileReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38195855/) where posted an Answer that did not meet original criteria, though provided solution, Kaiido accurately pointed out the appropriate context.

Comment: What do  you mean without a "server"?

Comment: @jdc91 Without requesting the file from a server and without server responding with data having `Content-Disposition` header. Using the browser to offer the download

Comment: What will be the contents of the file. Better if you can state the whole story!
Meanwhile, you can try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Comment: @jdc91 See _"Better if you can state the whole story!"_ See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38193605/how-to-updoad-in-old-browsers-ex-safari-5-1-4, https://stackoverflow.com/q/38195855/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are a number of ways of triggering a download. Following are a few:

Use a form:

```
<form method="get" action="mydoc.doc">
<button type="submit">Download</button>
</form>
```

Use javascript:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="window.open('mydoc.doc')">Download</button>
```

Comment: what if user has browser plugin which open mydoc.doc? then how it will be downloaded?

Comment: A user can choose to save content they see via a browser plugin. However, you can't force a download from the front-end. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8613725/how-can-i-force-download-with-html-and-or-javascript/8613899#8613899

Comment: `window.open("blob:xyz")` still works well for me in 2023 here's the reference; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Answer (score 3):

Although I support @LeoFarmer's answer, I would like to offer two "hackable" approaches:

1. If the file is very small, you can use `a` with the [`href='data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs).

   This could allow you to add content disposition in the `mediatype`, emulating an HTTP header. This hack is also not as portable as one might hope.
2. On small to medium files, it's possible to download the file using AJAX, and then [use the Javascript File API to prompt for file saving](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30832210/4025095) (the API doesn't support saving, but it's easy to convert the data to a data URL).

   If you want to avoid the Javascript File API, you can try emulating an anchor click, as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42815974/4025095).

Again, as pointed out by Leo Farmer, these solutions can't promise that the browser won't open the file in a new tab instead of saving it to the disk, but I think it's safe to say that all users will be able to gracefully degrade to a `cmd+S` or `ctrl+S` keyboard shortcut :-)

Answer (score 3):

> Use [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js#filesaverjs)

It supports all the commonly used browsers.

**Just include:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="FileSaver.min.js"></script>
```

**and use it like:**

```
var file = new File(["Hello, world!"], "hello world.txt", {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(file);
```

**Note:**
To make it work also in Safari < 6, Opera < 15 and FireFox < 20 you need to include [Blob.js](https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js) as a dependency.

Comment: Is `File` constructor available at the browsers mentioned  at last sentence of Answer?

Comment: No they don't. (http://caniuse.com/#search=File) But take a look at the documentation of FileSaver.js, there are other ways of saving it. I hope you'll find it helpful. :)

Comment: Amazing! It simply works, even with TypeScript and is probably the easiest way to do it in major browsers. I added "file-saver" to the "types" tsconfig option and used "saveAs" as a method anywhere in my project (needs to @ts-ignore the error in case of using it inside typescript modules). The minified version for distribution is [here](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/tree/master/dist).

Answer (score 2):

You may do this using both download attribute and jquery. download attribute don't support in ie and safari/ios. So you may use jquery to do that

```
 $('.download').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  //stop the browser from following
    window.location.href = 'uploads/file.doc';
});

<a href="no-script.html" class="download">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`data URI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) `data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>` representation of file either created manually or utilizing `FileReader()`, `.readAsDataURL()`, with [`MIME`](https://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/concepts/Internet_and_Web/mime_types) type set to [`application/octet-stream`](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/octet-stream), `encodeURIComponent()`, `window.open()`

```
<script>
  var file = "data:application/octet-stream,"
             + encodeURIComponent("<!DOCTYPE html>"
             + "<html><body>"
             + "<div>abc</div>"
             + "</body></html>");
  var saveFile = window.open(file, "_self");     
</script>
```

```
<script>
  var blob = new Blob(["abc"], {type:"text/plain"});
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
    // replace existing `MIME` type with `application/octet-stream`
    var file = "data:application/octet-stream;" 
                + e.target.result.split(/;/)[1];
    var saveFile = window.open(file, "_self");
  });
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
</script>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/IS1OC0laRwL3BuuF9zay?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

If you're using server-side then follow the form submission mechanism to render the page.
In MVC we can use below code

## Html

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("GetAttachment", "User", FormMethod.Post))
                {

                    <button type="submit">Download</button>   
                }
```

## MVC Controller

```
public ActionResult GetAttachment()
{
   string filename = "File.pdf";
string filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/Path/To/File/" + filename;
byte[] filedata = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filepath);

var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
{
    FileName = filename,
    Inline = true,
};

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());

return File(filedata, contentType);
}
```

Comment: _"without using `<a>` element with download attribute or a server?"_

Comment: using form we are submitting the data to server and server return the file.

Comment: A `<form>` does not need to be submitted to a server. The requirement of Question is to not use a server

Comment: can I use $.fileDownload('/url/to/download.pdf'); attribute?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: please refer this 
http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

Comment: Why is a jQuery plugin necessary?