# Downloading file instead of opening in javascript

Tags: javascript

I use a function http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.jpg to get the graph in jpg format.

I use it with `window.location.assign(cy.jpg());`, but it opens the image opens in the same tab.

I want it to download instead of opening in the tab. I guess I have to set `content-disposition = attachment` or something like that.

## Edit

I solved it with

```
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.download = 'filename.png';
link.href = cy.png();
link.click();
```

however, it is not compatible in all browsers.

Comment: It seems this function gives you the Base64 representation. One way to upload it could be to POST the value with enctype="multipart/form-data".

Comment: See this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52738739/export-cytoscape-graph-as-png-image-how-to-put-png-tag-on-cytoscape-graph

Comment: same code used but it open the file not download,i used the same code but it is not working for me. When i click download it open the file but not download MYCODE ' let a: any = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = fileName;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = 'display: none';
    a.click();
    a.remove();'

Answer (score 0):

You can set `<a>` element `href` attribute to result of `cy.png()`, set `download` attribute at `<a>` element, call `click()` on `<a>` element.

Alternatively, you can replace `MIME` type `"image/png"` portion of `data URI` returned by `cy.png()` with `"application/octet-stream"`, then set `location.href` to replacement `data URI`

```
  var url = cy.png();
  url = url.replace("image/png", "application/octet-stream");
  window.location.href = url;
```

See also [How to download a file without using <a> element with download attribute or a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711803/how-to-download-a-file-without-using-a-element-with-download-attribute-or-a-se)