# Export cytoscape graph as png image: how to put png tag on cytoscape graph

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I an novice in js and cytoscape. I want to display cytoscape graph in server with an save button for saving it as png. I checked cytoscape documentation but did not understand how to put an image tag on cytoscape graph. Please help me. I checked earlier posts in stackoverflow and github also.

My js script is here :

```
$(function(){ //
var cy = cytoscape({
container: document.getElementById('cy'),
style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
.selector('node')
  .css({
            'label': 'data(label)',
            'width': '60px',
            'height': '60px',
            'color': 'blue',
            'background-color': 'blue',
  })
   .selector('edge')
  .css({
            'text-background-color': 'blue',
            'text-background-opacity': 0.4,
            'width': '6px',
            'line-color': '#3C1515'})
 ,elements:{
 nodes:[
 { data: { id:"node1",label:" node1 " } },
 { data: { id:"node2",label:" node2 " } },
 { data: { id:"node3",label:" node3 " } }
  ],
  edges:[
 {"data": {"id": "12","source": "node1","target": "node2"}},
 {"data": {"id": "13","source": "node1","target": "node3"}}
 ]
 },
  layout: { name: "circle",directed: true,padding: 10 }

 });  // var cy cytoscope ends

 var png64 = cy.png();
 // put the png data in an img tag
 $('#png-eg').attr('src', png64);

  });
```

The html code is :

```
<html>
<style>
#cy {width: 80%;height: 80%;position: absolute;top: 20px;left: 20px;}
</style>
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="cytoscape.js"></script>
 <script src="javascript-code.js"></script>
   </head>
  <body>
 <div id="cy"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Hi, could you please mark the answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), else this question will not be closed and I don't get any carma for answering it :)

Comment: I have accepted. Sorry for delay. I was on leave. Thank you !

Comment: No problemo, everything clear now?

Comment: Yes! Thanks @StephanT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code simply doesn't contain the required img tag, so just add it to your html or add it with js/jquery:

```js
var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,

  style: [
    {
      selector: 'node',
      css: {
        'content': 'data(id)',
        'text-valign': 'center',
        'text-halign': 'center'
      }
    },
    {
      selector: '$node > node',
      css: {
        'padding-top': '10px',
        'padding-left': '10px',
        'padding-bottom': '10px',
        'padding-right': '10px',
        'text-valign': 'top',
        'text-halign': 'center',
        'background-color': '#bbb'
      }
    },
    {
      selector: 'edge',
      css: {
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
      }
    },
    {
      selector: ':selected',
      css: {
        'background-color': 'black',
        'line-color': 'black',
        'target-arrow-color': 'black',
        'source-arrow-color': 'black'
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [
      { data: { id: 'a', parent: 'b' }, position: { x: 215, y: 85 } },
      { data: { id: 'b' } },
      { data: { id: 'c', parent: 'b' }, position: { x: 300, y: 85 } },
      { data: { id: 'd' }, position: { x: 215, y: 175 } },
      { data: { id: 'e' } },
      { data: { id: 'f', parent: 'e' }, position: { x: 300, y: 175 } }
    ],
    edges: [
      { data: { id: 'ad', source: 'a', target: 'd' } },
      { data: { id: 'eb', source: 'e', target: 'b' } }

    ]
  },

  layout: {
    name: 'preset',
    padding: 5
  }
});
cy.ready(function () {
  //if you want to create the img tag afterwards:
  //$('#right').prepend("<img id='png-eg'>");
  
  var png64 = cy.png();
  // put the png data in an img tag
  $('#png-eg').attr('src', png64);
});
$("#clickMe").click(function () {
    var png64 = cy.png();
    // put the png data in an img tag
    $('#png-eg').attr('src', png64);
});
```

```css
body { 
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
}
#png-eg {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    min-width: 3em;
    min-height: 3em;
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- This code is for demonstration purposes only.  You should not hotlink to Github, Rawgit, or files from the Cytoscape.js documentation in your production apps. -->
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
<title>Compound nodes</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.2.17/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="cy"></div>
<div id="right"><button id="clickMe" style="float: right;">Click me</button><img id="png-eg"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Stephan T. for your reply. It is working. However, it saves the initial graph. Suppose, user edits the graph (like changes the node position) and wants to save that graph. How can it be implemented ?

Comment: Just use a button or sth like that, i will edit the answer for you :)

Comment: Thank you Stephan !

Comment: Glad I could help <3