# Downloading a PDF using JavaScript that is Cross Browser Compatible

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.5

I can download a PDF using AngularJS in Chrome, but this doesn't appear to work in the latest FireFox, Internet Explorer 11 or Edge (assuming it doesn't work for IE10 either), and I know a [shim is needed for IE9](https://github.com/eligrey/Blob.js).  Don't know if this the best shim for this if anyone has an opinion, but currently it doesn't seem to work. I tried it with a response type of `blob` and `arraybuffer` just in case that made a difference, and it doesn't.

All this counters what [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=createObjectURL) indicates about using the Blob URLs.  Anyone have this working in IE9 and up, and the last couple versions of FF, and can point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
$http({
    url: '/api/v1/download',
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: 'blob' // or 'arraybuffer'
}).then(function (response) {

    // Use the Blob object to create an object URL to download the file
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
    // var url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'})); // arraybuffer version

    // Create an anchor to perform download, but don't append to the DOM
    anchor.href = downloadUrl;
    anchor.download = filename;
    anchor.target = '_blank';
    anchor.click();

    URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);            
    anchor = null;

}).catch(function (reason) {

    console.log('FAIL', reason);
});
```

**UPDATE**

Currently the best (only) answer works for IE10, 11, Edge, FF, and continues to work with Chrome.  IE9 won't work using this solution if anyone has another polyfill/shim/other/etc, and Safari doesn't support the download attribute so the solution in the chosen answer doesn't work in an SPA since it just redirects the current page so in both these cases I've just left TODO stubs.

This is an update to the posted answer with more information added in comments for anyone to use or hopefully add to so IE9 and Safari work as expected:

```
    function performDownload(blob, filename) {

        // IE9 has no API for handling downloads using Blob objects, and doesn't support the download attribute
        if(isIE() == 9) {

            // TODO: polyfill/shim/other... change response type to?
        }
        // Only works for IE10 and up, including Edge
        else if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {

            // Provides a prompt to save the file to a location of users choice
            window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
        }
        // Browsers that adhere to current standards can implement downloads
        // using the Blob object with the download anchor attribute
        // ---
        // NOTE: Edge 13+ is compliant with both these standards, but Edge 12
        // does not support the download anchor attribute so all versions
        // have been grouped to use the propriety `msSaveBlob` method
        else {

            // Use the Blob object to create an object URL to download the file
            var URL = window.URL;
            var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            var anchor = document.createElement('a');

            if(angular.isDefined(anchor.download)) {

                anchor.href = downloadUrl;
                anchor.download = filename;
                anchor.target = '_blank';
                document.body.appendChild(anchor); // Required by Firefox
                anchor.click();

                // Release the existing object URL, and the anchor
                $timeout(function () {
                    URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);
                    document.body.removeChild(anchor);
                    anchor = null;
                }, 100);
            }
            else {

                // TODO: Safari does not support the download anchor attribute...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is `<a>` element appended to `document.body`? Are you revoking the `Blob URL` before download of resource occurs?

Comment: See also [How to download a file without using <a> element with download attribute or a server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711803/how-to-download-a-file-without-using-a-element-with-download-attribute-or-a-se)

Comment: Thanks @guest271314 I found the answer below meets what I need with respect to my question on browser compatibility since I could already download a file in Chrome, and all the duplicate question indicates is the same code I already had that only worked in Chrome.  My question wasn't how to download it was how to download it in different browsers.  Which turns out Firefox requires the anchor to be in the DOM so it needed appending unlike Chrome; and IE10, 11, and Edge require `msSaveBlob`.  Also, `application/octet-stream` in the other link has known issues in Safari according to caniuse.

Comment: The `javascript` at duplicate Question is not the same as `javascript` at present Question. `javascript` at linked Question appends `<a>` element to `document.body`, as mentioned at first comment. `application/octet-stream` approach is not only Answer or approach described at second link.

Comment: @guest271314 I was referring to the answer JS you gave to the question and just stating why I found the answer more useful below since it covers all the browsers except IE9.  While those answers don't work in IE10, 11, or Safari.  So they aren't from the perspective of browser compatibility.

Comment: Have not tried ie in some time. At which browsers does `javascript` at http://stackoverflow.com/a/31763030/ not return expected result?

Comment: Hi @guest271314 it doesn't seem to work for IE9, 10, or 11.  Only for Edge, Chrome, and FF.  IE10 and 11 sometimes opens an empty tab and other times it asks you open the blob using a local application, but both don't download a file.  IE10 and 11 do work if you use `window.navigator.msSaveBlob`.  The only issue is `msSaveBlob` isn't in IE9, and I can't find any solution/polyfill/shim for IE9, which is unfortunately still on our development radar :(

Answer (score 5):

I've used this with success in both IE11 and Chrome:

```
function saveBlob(response, contentType, filename) {
    let blob = new Blob([response.arrayBuffer()], { type: contentType });
    if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
        // IE workaround
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    } else {
        let URL = window.URL;
        let downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        if (filename) {
            let a = document.createElement('a');
            if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                window.location.href = downloadUrl;
            } else {
                a.href = downloadUrl;
                a.download = filename;
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
            }
        } else {
            window.location.href = downloadUrl;
        }
        // cleanup
        setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); }, 100); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great.  This solutions is working in IE10, 11, Edge, FF, and Chrome.  Need to test it in Safari and IE9 needs a shim for Blob and also `msSaveBlob`.  Not even sure how to test IE9 even if I found a polyfill for `msSaveBlob`.

Comment: If you want to test older versions of IE, Microsoft made some tools for that
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

Comment: Nice thanks @AndrewDiamond I ended up buying a months worth of https://www.browserstack.com since it allowed me to test IE9+, Chrome, and Firefox back a couple years on Windows 7, 8, 8.1, 10, and Safari 8+ on iOS for Yosemite+, as well as a bunch of mobile versions of each on different devices.

Comment: This guy saved my life.