# create html5 element on html4 page? doctype can't be changed

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, html4

We have two example websites:

http://fastpic.ru/ (html4 doctype)

and

http://imagebam.com/ (html5 doctype)

and I need to make a html5 element on both sites via javascript (userscript), the element is `<a>` with `download` attribute,

if you try to set a `download` attribute on html4 (1st) website it simply wouldn't work, you click it - it just opens the link when you click it, no `download` html5 behavior

So, is there a way to still create and use html5 element on a html4 website?

EDIT: found out firefox doesn't allow cross-origin (even subdomains) `download` attribute... damn, nothing works like it should in firefox...

Comment: The docytype on a document does not matter to browsers. Any browser that supports the `<a>` element with a `download` attribute will support it on any HTML document regardless of the doctype. So something else must be wrong at the http://fastpic.ru/ site that’s preventing it from working as expected.

Comment: You can use `data URI` with `MIME` type set to `"application/octet-stream"`, see [How to download a file without using <a> element with download attribute or a server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711803/how-to-download-a-file-without-using-a-element-with-download-attribute-or-a-se)

Answer (score -2):

You can try ta add this on the head of your html4 page

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
![endif]-->
```

Comment: Those are hacks to provide CSS support for HTML 5 elements in HTML 5 documents and for media queries, both in obsolete versions of Internet Explorer. Neither will provides support for the download attribute. Neither provide fixes for any problems caused by the choice of Doctype.