# Save DOM as xml in a file with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

In my javascript I have the following:

```
let person = document.createElement('person');
let name = document.createElement('name');
let surname = document.createElement('surname');
person.appendChild(name);
person.appendChild(surname);

let xml = person;
```

How do I save my "xml" variable in a file (using javascript only)?
OBS: The content should not be presented in a single line, but in the tree structure:

```
<person>
    <name></name>
    <surname></surname>
</person>
```

Comment: Client-side JS or server-side (Node)? Regarding the formatting, there are some existing library functions for pretty-printing XML.

Comment: Would you be willing to accept an answer with [JSON output instead of XML](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_xml.asp)? JS has native ways of serializing to JSON but not XML

Comment: I lied--there are native ways of serializing to XML using [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer). my answer uses it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a very simple way to serialize your document to XML using [`XMLSerializer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer).

Here is the process:

1. give an elment to XMLSerializer to serialize to XHTML (which is valid XML).
2. optionally remove the `xhtml` namespace using `String.prototype.replace`
3. use [vkbeautify](https://github.com/vkiryukhin/vkBeautify) to pretty print (no native way to pretty print)

```js
let person = document.createElement('person');
let name = document.createElement('name');
let surname = document.createElement('surname');
person.appendChild(name);
person.appendChild(surname);

// 1.) use XMLSerializer
let xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(person);

// 2.) remove xml namespace
let xmlWithoutNamespace = xml.replace(' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"', '');

// 3.) use vkbeautify or your other favorite library to pretty print
console.log(vkbeautify.xml(xmlWithoutNamespace));
```

```html
<script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/vkbeautify/vkbeautify.0.99.00.beta.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Kaiido thanks, i've updated it. the steps are simpler now.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Excellent post!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.outerHTML` to get string containing `person` node and child nodes, `data URI` representation of file, set a `href` of `<a>` element with `download` attribute set.

```js
let person = document.createElement('person');
let name = document.createElement('name');
let surname = document.createElement('surname');
person.appendChild(name);
person.appendChild(surname);

let xml = `data:application/xml,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>${encodeURIComponent(person.outerHTML)}`;

console.log(person, xml);

window.onload = () => {
  let a = document.createElement("a");
  let filename = "xmlfile.xml";
  a.download = a.textContent =  "xmlfile.xml";
  a.href = xml;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
}
```

You can alternatively create a `Blob` or `File` instance representing `XML` data

```js
let person = document.createElement('person');
let name = document.createElement('name');
let surname = document.createElement('surname');
person.appendChild(name);
person.appendChild(surname);

let xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>${person.outerHTML}`;

let file = new File([xml]
           , "xmlfile.xml", {type:"application/xml"});

console.log(person, xml, file);

let url;

window.onload = () => {
  let a = document.createElement("a");
  let filename = "xmlfile.xml";
  a.download = a.textContent =  "xmlfile.xml";
  url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  a.href = url;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.onclick = () => {
    window.onfocus = () => {
      window.onfocus = null;
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      if ("close" in file && !file.isClosed) file.close();
    }
  }
}
```

See also [How to download a file without using <a> element with download attribute or a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711803/how-to-download-a-file-without-using-a-element-with-download-attribute-or-a-se?s=1|3.2230)