# JavaScript: Save file via data URL in IE

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer

I have an app that converts files. I'm sending a file, and the converted file is being returned in the form of a data URL. Had everything working great in Chrome, but IE (10/11/Edge) is a different story. Have tried several things to no prevail:

1) HTML5 download attribute is not supported in IE. I tried assigning the returned URL as an anchor tag href, but invoking `.click()` is not supported, and manually clicking on the link does nothing.

2) window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob() and [File Saver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/). The SaveAs dialog pops up, but the blob is empty and never downloads anything.

```
var file= new Blob([returnedFile], {type: "application/pdf"});
window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(file, 'doc.pdf');
FileSaver.saveAs(file, 'doc.pdf');
```

Any ideas or suggestions to try?

Comment: What is `returnedFile`?

Comment: See [How to download a file without using <a> element with download attribute or a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711803/how-to-download-a-file-without-using-a-element-with-download-attribute-or-a-se?)

Comment: @guest271314 returnedFile is the data URL of the converted file I'm getting back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up getting the browser via `navigator.userAgent.match` and handling the save based on each browser accordingly:

```
 var saveData = (data, fileName) => {
```

IE:

```
FileSaver.saveAs(blob, fileName + "." + extension);
```

Chrome:

```
var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
downloadLink.style.display = "none";
downloadLink.href = data;
downloadLink.download = fileName;
downloadLink.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, try to verify `saveAs` existance:

```
if (window.saveAs) { 
    window.saveAs(blob, name); 
} else { 
    navigator.saveBlob(blob, name); 
}
```

As for the `Blob` itself:

- create `<a>`
- update `href`:

  a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(returnedFile, {type: "application/pdf"}));
- fire `click` event

More or less the same functionality can be reviewed there: http://jsfiddle.net/VB59f/2/

Comment: The loop reverted to navigator.saveBlob, but still did not prompt a save. Creating the <a> tag is what I had originally and works perfectly for Chrome, but gives Access is denied/Invalid state error in IE.

Comment: @user7674254, when you're taking the file, be sure that you're allowed to grab it (by extra-header: `X-Content-Security-Policy`, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, and etc)