# angular 2 project: save downloaded file in assets folder

Tags: file, download, angular2-services

I have an angular 2 project that allows me to download files through a service and I know the file has been successfully downloaded as I can see the following console message:

```
this.rest.getGeometry(this.stlLocation).subscribe(data => console.log('file downloaded successfully'));
```

A look at the Network tab in the "Developer tools" confirms that the download was successful.

is it possible to save the file to a local folder such as src/app/assets?

Thank you for your help,

Dino

Comment: Nope, only user is able to define path

Comment: OK, any idea in how to make the user save to a specific location of his choice and record that location for future use?

Comment: Check that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44462162/javascript-save-file-via-data-url-in-ie/44462246#44462246 ; but I'm not sure that you would be able to record the location

Comment: I also have same problem. Need to write images in assets folder in angular2 app