# Electron - How to save base64 dataUrl to file

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, electron

I'm working with an existing Electron project (convert web app to desktop app), which has a task that is to export content on screen to pdf/png/jpg.

Here is the situation:

1. The desktop app is purely client-side code, it doesn't connect to any API or server (just in case you suggest a solution using Nodejs server-side code)
2. I got the dataUrl from canvas object already (it's a base64 string of the file)

How can I save that dataUrl into a file (pdf/png/jpg)?

Here are some ways that I tried:

1. The good old window.location = dataUrl (nothing happens)
2. Create a form inside the div, action = dataUrl, then submit the form

Both ways are not working!

Thank you very much

Comment: You can use `<a>` element with `download` attribute and `href` set to the `data URI`

Comment: Convert it to a [blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript) and write it to a file.

Comment: @BenFortune: Thank you. Can you please provide a sample code here?

Answer (score 0):

For the download to occur the MIME type of the `data URI` needs to be changed to `"application/octet-stream"`

```js
var dataURL = "data:text/plain,123";
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.action = dataURL.replace(/:[\w-/]+(?=,)/, ":application/octet-stream");
form.method = "GET";
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

Using `<a>` element with `download` attribute

```js
var dataURL = "data:text/plain,123";
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.download = "file";
a.href = dataURL;
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
```

See also [How to download a file without using <a> element with download attribute or a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711803/how-to-download-a-file-without-using-a-element-with-download-attribute-or-a-se)?

Comment: Thank you @guest271314. I tried both ways but it just doesn't work. No error in console log but file is not downloaded

Comment: @HoangTrinh Have not tried electron. Is the environment a `window` and HTML `document`?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/h0z341 Yes, there is **window** and also **document**, but it just doesn't work in Electron, this environment is so weird